# How to distinguish between arrow key and numpad in WindowProc handler?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a C++ application for Windows and I would like to provide an input system that feels really nice but there are some edge cases where a user can press numpad keys, e.g. Numpad 2 with numlock off or the shift key down which will cause the corresponding `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN` events to be for Arrow Key Down.

Comment: Why? The universal convention is that with Num Lock off, numpad 4/8/6/2 are equivalent to the arrow keys. Every other Windows application respects that.

Comment: You can check to see if the NumLock key is on or off using [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

Comment: I would like to handle numpad keys like numpad keys regardless of shift or numpad state tho.

Comment: look for [*lParam*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) - for scan code and 24-bit which Indicates whether the key is an extended key. simply do dbgprint of lparam on different arrow key down and you view different

Comment: *handle numpad keys like numpad keys* is exactly what happens. Numpad keys do different things based on the state of the NumLock key. If you handle them always in one way, you're violating both the standard use of them and the user's expectations as to how they will work. I don't know what your goal is here, but it appears to be very misguided.

Comment: My goal is not text input. lParam currently looks very promising; can't believe the answer might've been in that unused forth parameter. 

Comment: Well, the "extended" bit seems to be 0 for arrow keys and 1 for numpad keys, not sure if that's intentional, but it works as nicely as I want it to now. :D

Comment: @Sainan yes, it is intentional. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags): "*The extended-key flag indicates whether the keystroke message originated from one of the additional keys on the enhanced keyboard. The extended keys consist of ... **arrow keys in the clusters to the left of the numeric keypad** ... The extended-key flag is set if the key is an extended key.*"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using extended keys to distinguish between arrow keys and numeric keys, we can also use [GetKeyNameText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeynametexta) to obtain the string of key names. Even when Num Lock is off, we can still read the names of numeric keys correctly.

According to the [GetKeyNameText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeynametexta):we can use:

GetKeyNameText(lParam, KeyNameBuffer, sizeof(KeyNameBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR));

After the call, the function will return the name of the current key. The arrow keys are: Up Down Left Right, and the numeric keys are: Num 8 Num 2 Num 4 Num 6, so that we can simply distinguish between arrow keys and numeric keys.

Here is the sample:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; 
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    { 
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd,iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    TCHAR szKeyName[32];
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        GetKeyNameText(lParam, szKeyName, sizeof(szKeyName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        MessageBox(0, szKeyName, "title", 0);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When you press the button, a dialog box with the button name will pop up.

Comment: `GetKeyNameText` returns a *localized* version of the key name. To make things worse, those names are provided by the keyboard driver. To distinguish between keys you have to compare against all combinations of languages and keyboard drivers, past, present, and future.